# Buildfire: How to use the Barcode Scanner

Tags: camera, barcode, buildfire

I have gotten to the point where I can launch the barcode mock mode.
I am trying to figure out how I can start scanning test codes in development.
Or would an app that I am trying to test this on, need to have camera permissions on the app?

In that case, how do you overcome the use of the Camera Hardware on the PWA?

Or is there a way that I can scan QR-Codes using a different javascript API that would work in all cases?

Also, I had to move the camera and barcode service Javascript files into my Widget folder because when I was trying to reference them as you do on the instructions, the files wouldn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when you are in web it will mock the functionality because you're not on a device. There are HTML5 Camera API's see (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

You can use the BuildFire Previewer App (contact customer support if you havent downloaded it yet)

While you can take a copy of the services into your plugin it is risky. If we issue any updates or bug fixes you will not receive them. Also if it breaks compatibility at any time (rare but possible) your plugin stop working